# Identifying unf, 1nf, 2nf, 3nf in Database Normalization

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

> ... instructor. The UNF relation has been provided.

```
                             Premiere Corporation
                             Order Detail Report
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| Order |    Order       | Cust| Cust    | Part | Part         | Qty | Quoted |
| Number|    Date        | Num | Last Nam|Number| Desc.        | Ord | Price  |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12489 | 2016-09-02 124 | 124 | Adams   | AX12 | Iron         |  11 | 14.95  |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12491 | 2016-09-02 311 | 311 | Charles | BT04 | Gas Grill    |  3  | 440.00 |
|       |                |     |         | BZ66 | Washer       |  1  | 399.99 |
|       |                |     |         | CX11 | Mini Blender |  1  | 11.98  |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12494 | 2016-09-04     | 315 | Daniels | CB03 | Bike         |  4  | 279.96 |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12495 | 2016-09-04     | 256 | Samuels | CX11 | Mini Blender |  2  | 23.96  |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12498 | 2016-09-05     | 522 | Nelson  | AZ52 | Dartboard    |  2  | 12.96  |
|       |                |     |         | BA74 | Basketball   |  4  | 24.96  |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12500 | 2016-09-05     | 124 | Adams   | BT04 | Gas Grill    |  1  | 149.99 |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
| 12504 | 2016-09-05     | 522 | Nelson  | CZ81 | Treadmill    |  2  | 325.98 |
+-------+----------------+-----+---------+------+--------------+-----+--------+
```

#### UNF

ORDER [**`OrderNo`**, Orderdate, CustNo, CustLname, (PartNo, PartDesc, QtyOrd, Price)]

#### 1NF

ORDER [**`OrderNo, PartNo`**, Orderdate, CustNo, CustLname, PartDesc, QtyOrd, Price]

#### 2NF

ORDER [**`OrderNo`**, Orderdate, CustNo, CustLname, QtyOrd, Price]

PART [**`PartNo`**, PartDesc]

ORDER_PART [**`OrderNo (FK), PartNo (FK)`**]

#### 3NF

ORDER [**`OrderNo`**, Orderdate, **`CustNo (FK)`**,  QtyOrd, Price]

CUSTOMER [**`CustNo`**, CustLname]

PART [**`PartNo`**, PartDesc]

ORDER_PART [**`OrderNo (FK), PartNo (FK)`**]

---

I need to normalize data into unf to 3nf. Though, i am not sure what i have done is correct.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS ["UNF/ "1NF" have no 1 meaning.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)

Comment: 3NF Hint (1): "Every fact depends on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key." What do `Qty Ordered` and `Quot. Price` depend on?

Comment: 3NF Hint (2): What does it mean for `CustNo` to be underlined in `ORDER`?

Comment: 2NF Hint (3): Sort out 3NF first, then revisit your reasoning about 2NF.